# Get "Foo" queryset of ForeignKey relationships for initial "Bar" queryset?

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have a simple `ForeignKey` relationship:

```py
class Foo(models.Model):
  id = UUIDField()

class Bar(models.Model):
  id = UUIDField()
  foo = ForeignKey(foo)
```

If I have an initial `queryset` of `Bar` objects, how can I get a queryset of related `Foo` object for each respective `Bar`?

I'm currently doing this but I'm wondering if there's a better way:

```py
bar_qs = Bar.objects.all().select_related("foo")

foo_ids = []
for i in bar_qs:
  foo_ids.append(i.foo.id)

foo_qs = Foo.objects.filter(id__in=foo_ids)
```

Comment: You could do: `Foo.objects.filter(id__in=Bar.objects.all().values('foo'))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query:

```py
Foo.objects.filter(bar_set__in=Bar.objects.all())
```

Answer (score 0):

You're doing the right thing in using `select_related` because that gathers the related `foo` object in the same query so there's no need to query the database again for the `Foo` table.

If a list of foos is ok, you could just do;

```
bar_qs = Bar.objects.all().select_related("foo")

foos = []
for i in bar_qs:
    foos.append(i.foo)
```

Or you could just start with the `foo` queryset using;

```
foo_qs = Bar.objects.select_related('foo').only('foo')
```

But if you need a `bar_qs`, then you'd be best doing;

```
bar_qs = Bar.objects.all().select_related("foo")
foo_qs = bar_qs.only('foo')
```

Comment: Unfortunately `foos` is a `list` and not a `queryset`.  I think joining the `objects` in `foo` into a `queryset` would require another `for` loop?

Comment: @Chris I've updated my answer to limit the queryset to 1 field